# Getting a token for Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are looking at Windows Azure, but getting a token appears to be hard now, at least that's what I'm seeing in web searches. Anyone tried it or know how to accelerate that process?

Any idea how long this typically takes?

Any help appreciated // :)

Comment: It was about two weeks for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get one if you are a US resident from CodeProject directly. Go to http://www.codeproject.com and you get your token instantly. They only have 500 so be quick.